# Confusion with common::Time::SecToNano()

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As the description of the function says it converts seconds to nanoseconds, but the [actual code](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/dae44f8efd4eddfe5d0e47f614d9b1fb0abfd3bb/gazebo/common/Time.hh?at=default#cl-380) doing the opposite. So, instead of multiplying seconds with `1e9`, it multiplying it with `1e-9`.

Similar applies to `MilToNano()` and `MicToNano()`.

What I am missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2334/confusion-with-common::time::sectonano()/) by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-04-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-04-11**:
I see it the same way, it might be a bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It's a [bug](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/640/tonano-functions-convert-in-the-wrong), with a [pending fix](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/438/fix-tonano-functions-with-test/diff).

Thanks for the report.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1